# Which Python module should be used for the Google Client API verify_oauth2_token

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

This google documentation web page,[verify-google-id-token](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token), says I should use Python modules google.oauth2 and `google.auth.transport` in order to call the verify_oauth2_token api.

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests

# (Receive token by HTTPS POST)
# ...

def test():
    try:
        # Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
        idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token("token", requests.Request(), "CLIENT_ID")

        # Or, if multiple clients access the backend server:
        # idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request())
        # if idinfo['aud'] not in [CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]:
        #     raise ValueError('Could not verify audience.')

        # If auth request is from a G Suite domain:
        # if idinfo['hd'] != GSUITE_DOMAIN_NAME:
        #     raise ValueError('Wrong hosted domain.')

        # ID token is valid. Get the user's Google Account ID from the decoded token.
        userid = idinfo['sub']
        print("hello")
    except ValueError:
        # Invalid token
        print("fail")
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

However, when I refence those modules in my Python app I get This error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google.oauth2 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for google.oauth2

This would seem to indicate that this module does not exist.
Same error occurs when I reference google.auth.transport first:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google.auth.transport (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for google.auth.transport

Are these supported modules or should I be using something else?

I tried reference these modules in my requirements.txt file and expected them to be found and loaded.  This is not the case so I would like to know which Python modules I should use to resolve the api referenced.

Answer (score 0):

its working fine for me but I have all of these packages installed

- google-api-core          2.11.0
- google-api-python-client 2.62.0
- google-auth              2.17.3
- google-auth-httplib2     0.1.0
- google-auth-oauthlib     0.5.3
- googleapis-common-protos 1.56.4

Could you be missing one?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I'm still getting an error when it tries to load google-auth-httplib2
Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.auth.httplib2'. Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 380, in _handle__function_load_request